# Which actors were originally considered for the role of Data in the Star Trek: The Next Generation series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes, actors

Please include all who were approached and maybe those who auditioned and later became famous.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A 1987 memo between Paramount execs gives the following names:

- Mark Lindsay Chapman
- Eric Menyuk
- Kevin Peter Hall (also for Geordi)
- Kelvin Han Yee

Note the obvious absence of any actors that actually were cast as regulars on the series and, of course, **Brent Spiner**!

UPDATE: [Memo was uncovered by Letters of Note](http://www.lettersofnote.com/2010/08/star-trekcasting.html) a year or so ago.

[image]

Comment: Damn! I never thought that would be answered!

Comment: Outstanding! Source?

Comment: I added the original source.

Comment: Wow! Wesley Snipes for Geordi haha... and Tim Russ too.

Comment: I just noticed... no Worf?!? Maybe that's another good question to post.

Comment: Was Worf even in the Main Cast in Season 1?

Comment: He was a pilot in the first season. He took over as security when Tasha Yar was killed toward the end of that season.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but that's what I meant http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1036/was-the-worf-from-star-trek-the-next-generation-an-afterthought

Comment: Wow, Yaphet Kotto as Picard, that would've been something.

Comment: "Denise Crosby seems to be the only possibility for Troi". Thank God no!

Comment: Jenny Agutter (I assume that's who they mean) as Beverley would have been interesting.

Comment: This is the funniest thing I've read in a long time!  Wow!!

Comment: Rosalind Chao for Tasha Yar?  Would have been a very different take on the character, I'm sure!  I wish I could see episodes from some alternate universe where that casting choice happened.

Comment: Eric Menyuk would show up as [The Traveler](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Traveler).

Comment: Julia Nickson as Tasha? Hubba hubba.

Comment: @steveha: I loved when Farscape almost did that for an episode :)

Comment: Cheryl McFadden is usually called Gates McFadden.

Comment: Tim Russ in there again!